# Advection-diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The advection-diffusion equation I am working with has the form
$$
            \frac{\partial c}{\partial t}  =  \nabla\cdot (D\nabla c) - \nabla\cdot (vc) + R ,
$$
where
\begin{aligned}
                       c &= \text {concentration}
\\
                       t &= \text{time}
\\
                       D &= \text{Diffusivity}
\\
                      \nabla &=\text {Gradient}
\\
                      \nabla\cdot &= \text{Divergence}
\\
                       R &= \text{Source of quantity } c
\\
\end{aligned}
I am unsure of what to do with the del operators.  Could you help me set up the 
equation for Integration?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything is a function of spatial coordinates $x,y,z$ and time $t$,
$$\eqalign{\nabla \cdot (D \nabla c) &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(D \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial x}\right) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(D \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial y}\right) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(D \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial z}\right)\cr
&= D \left( \dfrac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2} +\dfrac{\partial^2 c}{\partial y^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 c}{\partial z^2} \right) + \dfrac{\partial D}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial D}{\partial y} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial D}{\partial z} \dfrac{\partial c}{\partial z} }$$
and similarly if $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$
$$\nabla . (c v) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} (c v_1) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(c v_2) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(c v_3)$$